What would happen if someone were to wear a breathing restriction mask when sleeping over several nights to acclimatize for mountaineering?
I’m an amateur mountaineer and current student in the health field wondering what the effects would be if one was to wear a breathing restriction mask (typically designed for athletes to use during exercise) every night as they slept, turning up the resistance over time. Would this theoretically be a safe way to prepare for mountaineering and decrease the probability of a HAPE/HACE incident when ascending?
Going further, for more serious expeditions, would a hypobaric chamber or some sort of hypobaric breathing mask be useful for further acclimation? Could one theoretically acclimatize to altitudes of 6,000+ meters without ever leaving the ground, or is there something altitude provides beyond simply less atmospheric pressure that needs to be acclimated to.
Finally, would this process be made more comfortable if the lower pressure air was supplemented by an inert gas like nitrogen, simulating breathing at full capacity but only having a limited amount of oxygen?
Settling a debate I had with a circle of friends who are also either involved in healthcare or mountaineering fields.

Breathing restriction masks do not simulate altitude, they just make breathing more difficult mechanically. Altitude lowers the partial pressure of oxygen, which triggers a bunch of hematologic changes. Restriction masks may strengthen the respiratory muscles and be otherwise useful in athletic training (findings differ), but they definitely do not trigger the hematologic changes needed for altitude acclimatization. See Altitude Training Masks Do They Work? (the linked article is not peer reviewed but contains a helpful list of references that are peer reviewed).

Finally, would this process be made more comfortable if the lower
pressure air was supplemented by an inert gas like nitrogen,
simulating breathing at full capacity but only having a limited amount
of oxygen?

This is called a hyponormic chamber. There have been multiple studies using hyponormic and hypobaric chambers to achieve improved acclimatization to altitude. The results are all over the map. Most studies were small and everyone seems to come up with their own protocol, so comparisons are difficult. This review Hypoxia Conditioning for High-Altitude Pre-acclimatization may be helpful.
Hypnormic tents have been an attractive target for athletes because they are so much cheaper and widely available than hypobaric chambers. Dr. Monica Piris is a physician, an expeditionary climber, and a coach for high altitude climbers. From her practice she is skeptical of the value of hyponormic tents for acclimatization, but thinks there may be some value in intermittent exercise using a hyponormic mask. The value is not acclimatization, but improved ability to achieve maximum exertion at altitude.
